# Python set.add() is triggering outside a conditional statement

Tags: python, set, tokenize

I'm tokenizing some document and I want to find out which tokens are shared between one or more tokenizations. To do this, for each tokenization, I am looping through the set of all tokens in all tokenizations, called `all_tokens` and checking if a given token exists in the current tokenization. If it does exist in the current tokenization, I add the index of the tokenization `i` to a set corresponding to the token in the `token_dict` dictionary. However, `set.add()` is somehow being called outside the conditional, resulting in every `i` being added to the token's entry in the `token_dict`. I've set up a small toy version here where I check the final token's entry in the `token_dict`.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
all_tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
tokenizations = [[all_tokens[np.random.randint(0, len(all_tokens))] for i in range(4)] for i in range(10)]
print(tokenizations)
token_dict = dict.fromkeys(all_tokens, set())
for i, tokenization in enumerate(tokenizations):
    token_set = set(tokenization)
    for token in all_tokens:
        #for each token in the total vocabulary, check if the unique value exists in the tokenization
        if token in token_set:
            token_dict[token].add(i)
        if(token=='g'):
            print(token in token_set)


print(token)
print(token_dict[token])
```

This results in the output:

```
[['g', 'd', 'e', 'g'], ['c', 'e', 'e', 'g'], ['b', 'c', 'g', 'c'], ['c', 'e', 'd', 'c'], ['f', 'e', 'b', 'd'], ['f', 'f', 'b', 'd'], ['e', 'a', 'd', 'b'], ['f', 'e', 'd', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'c', 'g'], ['b', 'd', 'd', 'g']]
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
True
True
g
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

As you can see, `g` does not exist in the tokenizations at indices 3-7 and the conditional correctly identifies this as `False`, but the indices of those tokenizations are added to the entry of `g` in the `token_dict`.

If I change the `token_dict` values to a `list`, and use `list.append()`, the output shows every index appended to the `list` 3 times.
`[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]`

I don't show it here but this is true for all tokens in `all_tokens`. Why is this happening?

Comment: On line 4, this code prints `tokenizations` before it is even defined.  Please post working code.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry about that, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set.add` is only called inside the conditional. The problem is: there is only one set, and all entries in `token_dict` point to the exact same set instance.

The culprit is this line:

```py
token_dict = dict.fromkeys(all_tokens, set())
```

From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

> All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.

Following their advice, you should use a dict comprehension instead:

```py
token_dict = {token: set() for token in all_tokens}
```

This creates a new `set` instance for each item in `token_dict`.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I still don't understand why set.add() was triggering outside the conditional but I'm glad it works anyway

Comment: @DLS I added a brief explanation to my answer. If it is still unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

all_tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

tokenizations = [[all_tokens[np.random.randint(0, len(all_tokens))] for i in range(4)] for i in range(10)]
token_dict = dict.fromkeys(all_tokens, set())
for i, tokenization in enumerate(tokenizations):
    token_set = set(tokenization)
    for token in all_tokens:
        #for each token in the total vocabulary, check if the unique value exists in the tokenization
        if token in token_set:
            token_dict[token].add(i)
        if(token=='g'):
            print(token in token_set)


print(token)
print(token_dict[token])
```

Try this may work !!!

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work unfortunately. It still outputs all indices 0-9 for the `set` in g's entry in the `token_dict.`

Comment: Please add an explanation of what you have changed, and how/why this solves the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).